# TempData persistence

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I've been working with `TempData` lately and facing a confusing case:

Supposing that the `TempData` is created in the following Action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction1()
{
  //...
  myTempData = TempData["myTempData"];
  //..
}
```

and is expected to be use in the following Action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction2()
{
  //...
  TempData["myTempData"] = myTempData;
  //..
}
```

I understand that if I call `MyAction2` on the next request, the `TempData` value will be deleted. But if I call other action, not `MyAction2`, on the next request, will `TempData` be deleted? If it will be, is there any trick to make sure it exist until the end of the session?

Thanks all.

Comment: Have you tried it to find out?  It is my understanding that this uses session to store the data and is wiped out when the data is read, unless it is read with .Peek

Comment: It will be available in subsequent request (redirection), no matter which `action method` you are about to call.

Comment: @Slicksim I think so, too but not quite sure :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Here you go for Keep and Peek Temp Data For next Request :**

If you won't read Temp Data then it will be available for next subsequent request

> So let’s discuss these four conditions in more detail
>
> “Tempdata helps to preserve values for a single request”.
>
> The other half-truth which developers do not know is or I will say which confuses developer is:
>
> “TempData CAN ALSO preserve values for the next request depending on 4 conditions”..
>
> 1. Not Read
> 2. Normal Read
> 3. Read and Keep
> 4. Peek and Read
>
> Condition 1 (Not read): If you set a “TempData” inside your action and if you do not read it in your view, then “TempData” will be persisted for the next request.
>
> Condition 2 (Normal Read): If you read the “TempData” normally like the below code, it will not persist for the next request.
>
> ```
>    stringstr = TempData["MyData"];
> ```
>
> Even if you are displaying, it’s a normal read like the code below:
>
> ```
>    @TempData["MyData"];
> ```
>
> Condition 3 (Read and Keep): If you read the “TempData” and call the “Keep” method, it will be persisted.
>
> ```
>    @TempData["MyData"];
>    TempData.Keep("MyData");
> ```
>
> Condition 4 ( Peek and Read): If you read “TempData” by using the “Peek” method, it will persist for the next request.
>
> ```
>    stringstr = TempData.Peek("Td").ToString();
> ```

Comment: So it's like Request 1 I create the `TempData`, Request 2 3 4 I do not read it but call other Action instead, then on Request 5 the `TempData` is still there?

Answer (score 1):

```
TempData["myTempData"]
```

1) TempData persistence only on action to action, suppose **action1** calls you have store the data into **TempData["myTempData"]** then you need the access data in **action2** that will definity persist.

2) if you want to store the data in **TempData["myTempData"]** then on each and every action first assign the value of **TempData["myTempData"]** to **TempData["myTempData"]** then use it in every action until you will removed it forcefully.

Hopefully query will resolved.

Comment: Thank you :D I'll consider using your solution :D