# Issue with persisting values in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, state-management

I'm having an odd issue with ASP.NET Core MVC.

I'm trying to keep track of a Guid called `Uid` as I move from page to page in an app at work.

In the controller, I tried setting each of these as a test on my Edit action.

```
model.Uid = uid.ToString();
TempData["Uid"] = uid.ToString();
ViewData["Uid"] = uid.ToString();
```

But as I step through the application, when I navigate through the pages, these values are all reset to null when I'd expect them to persist.

I could swear I've used these before and they persisted... any ideas for how I might narrow down the cause?

Comment: Try `TempData.Keep("Uid")` to persist the value.  You can also use `TempData.Peek("Uid")` to get the value without marking the value for deletion.  (Temp data will delete values that have been read).

Comment: Does this answer your question? **1)** [TempData persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096482/tempdata-persistence)  **2)** [ViewBag/ViewData Lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9186855/6630084)

Comment: @hijinxbassist Thanks for pointing that out. I had `TempData.Keep()` - but I changed it to `TempData.Keep("Uid")` and tested. Unfortunately it still isn't persisting the value.

This was a solution set up by another dev that I don't have access to.  Is it possible that there is some config setting that prevents these values from persisting when they otherwise should?

Comment: By default TempData uses the Session to store the values.  You can also implement a custom provider.  Check which session mode (if any) was chosen by looking for the sessionState node in the web.config.

Comment: @hijinxbassist Interesting. Since it is a Core app, it didn't have a web.config - but I added one in the root with the following.

`<system.web><sessionState cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" /></system.web>`

Unfortunately, when I tested it, the values were still not persisting.

Comment: Try this:  Inside of `Startup.cs`, inside the `ConfigureServices` function add `services.AddSession();`  and inside `Configure` function BEFORE `UseMvc` line, add `app.UseSession();`

Comment: @hijinxbassist The only mention of MVC in `Startup.cs` was `services.AddMvc();`.

When I added `UseMvc` it gave a warning that I had to set the MVC option `EnableEndpointRouting = false`.  

I did that as follows:
`services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);`

When I tested though, `TempData`, `ViewData`, and `model` values were still not persisting.

Comment: You should add `services.AddSession()`, not changing the `AddMvc` call.  The second is to enable the session in the app, via `app.UseSession()` inside of the `Configure` function.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I did add `services.AddSession()` and `app.UseSession()` as described. When I removed the options from AddMvc I get the following error though.

`System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Endpoint Routing does not support 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc(...)'. To use 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc' set 'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside 'ConfigureServices(...).
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`